# Publishing built files to gh-pages with Travis CI

Tags: github, travis-ci, github-pages

For [this](https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-component-button) repository I'm trying to publish the built files using Travis CI.

I'm following [these instructions](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/). IIUC setting `skip_cleanup` to true should make Travis also publish the `target` folder containing the built resources, however I don't see these resources. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to delete the `target` folder from `.gitignore` in order to get the travis commit to `gh-pages` to work.  Not ideal because `target` resources should not be pushed to the master branch.  There's a Travis issue tracking it [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7490).

### Update

The end game solution ended up being adding this to my travis configuration:

```
before_deploy:
    - sed -i '/target/d' .gitignore
```

That will cause Travis to delete the target folder from .gitignore right before attempting the deploy to github pages.  This is OK because it's only done on the Travis end, and not in the master branch on the github end.  Full sample travis configuration [here](https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-component-button/blob/master/.travis.yml).